# As3 number and array

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi i'm trying to create a dynamic that small pictures using  gg class . and i want to get a big picture when i click on the smaller one .
but the problem i don't know how to get the
here's the code

```
    var box:Box = new Box ();
    addChild(box);

    var myXml:XML;
    var yp:Number = 50;

    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest ("filXml.xml"));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,readXml);
```

Comment: Maybe it's better that you share with us the content of your xml file ?!

Comment: I second that comment, we need to see a sample of your xml file.

Comment: hi : i added the xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML, you'v used different attribute names for your "big" picture, which is not recommended. You have to use the same attributes for all your XML lines which live in the same parent element, so you can do like this, for example :

```
<pictures>
    <picture small="pic1.jpg" big="Bpic1.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic2.jpg" big="Bpic2.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic3.jpg" big="Bpic3.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic4.jpg" big="Bpic4.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic5.jpg" big="Bpic5.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic6.jpg" big="Bpic6.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic7.jpg" big="Bpic7.jpg"></picture>
    <picture small="pic8.jpg" big="Bpic8.jpg"></picture>
</pictures>
```

Then in your ActionScript code, you can use, for example, an array to store your big pictures names and store the small picture index in the `name` attribute of its `Loader` object, then when it's pressed, you have just to select the big picture from the big pictures array.

```
var big_pictures:Array = [];

function readXml(e:Event):void
{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < xml.picture.length(); i++)
    {
        var xml_line:XML = xml.picture[i];

        // store big pictures names
        big_pictures.push(xml_line.@big);

        var loader:UILoader = new UILoader();
            loader.name = String(i);

            // ...

            loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showBigPic);              
        addChild(loader);
    }       
}

function showBigPic (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(big_pictures[int(e.currentTarget.name)]);
}
```

Hope that can help.